# CCNode does not have a member named 'indexOf'

Tags: swift

I am following [Make School's Hoppy Bunny tutorial](https://www.makeschool.com/tutorials/build-flappy-bird-with-spritebuilder-and-cocos2d-in-swift/adding-obstacles) (link is to the portion of the tutorial posted here).

I experienced a problem when

```
for obstacle in Array(obstacles.reverse()) {
  let obstacleWorldPosition = gamePhysicsNode.convertToWorldSpace(obstacle.position)
  let obstacleScreenPosition = convertToNodeSpace(obstacleWorldPosition)

  //obstacle moved past left side of screen?
  if obstacleScreenPosition.x < (-obstacle.contentSize.width) {
    obstacle.removeFromParent()
    obstacles.removeAtIndex(obstacles.indexOf(obstacle)!)

    //for each removed obstacle, add a new one
    spawnNewObstacle()
  }
}
```

`obstacles.removeAtIndex(obstacles.indexOf(obstacle)!)` gave me an error saying

```
[CCNode] does not have a member named 'indexOf'
```

what do I do?

Comment: You should include a link to the tutorial. Yes, people can search for it but why make them do the extra work? It will just cut down on the responses to your question.

Comment: Also, how are you declaring the variable `obstacles`? You should include that line in your example.

Answer (score 0):

From the information given I can't see what is holding up the use of the `indexOf()` on your `Array` but the code you've posted is pretty convoluted. You're basically filtering out obstacles, why not use the `filter()` method instead? Here is the same code rewritten to use `filter()`:

```
var numberRemoved = 0

// filter iterates through the Collection and creates a new Collection that contains the items for which the closure returns true
obstacles = obstacles.filter { obstacle in
  let obstacleWorldPosition =  gamePhysicsNode.convertToWorldSpace(obstacle.position)
  let obstacleScreenPosition = convertToNodeSpace(obstacleWorldPosition)

  // if the test in guard is false then perform the code block after else
  // keep the obstacle by returning true
  guard obstacleScreenPosition.x < (-obstacle.contentSize.width) else { return true }

  // remove the obstacle
  obstacle.removeFromParent()
  numberRemoved += 1 // keep a count of removed
  // remove the obstacle by returning false
  return false
}

// add new ones to replace removed ones
for _ in 0..<numberRemoved {
  spawnNewObstacle()
}
```

Try this code, it might eliminate your error and it's a better way to perform the task.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. I'm extremely new and the code I'm using is from Make School's tutorial, although I don't understand half of it. Do you know of any free app development tutorials or courses for absolute beginners? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried any myself but I believe that iTunes University has some courses. The one I know about is [Stanford's Developing iOS 8 Apps with Swift](https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-8-apps-swift/id961180099) but I'm sure there are others.